# Run angular 7 dotnet core project on local IIS in development

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, iis, visual-studio-2017

I have an angular7/dotnet core project template in same project and i want to run it on local iis without publishing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Visual Studio make a production build of your project:
'ng build --prod'

This should create the dist folder in the root of your project. Now all you need to do is point the IIS site to the project folder in that dist folder and as long as you have the necessary features installed on IIS it should work as a regular website.
There is a more in depth guide here: https://blog.angularindepth.com/deploy-an-angular-application-to-iis-60a0897742e7

Not sure if this was what you were looking for but hope it helps. If not please expand on your original question so we have a better understanding of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Nice explanation but I have 2 projects (Dotnet core for backend/ Angular for frontend) using builtin visual studio 2017 template. I have already deployed angular and web api independently on IIS but problem occurs when using both in SAME PROJECT. Also I dont want to publish just want to set development environment on Local IIS rather than IIS express.